# Excel view data in 1 worksheet based on value in another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

Morning

My first post, so here goes!

I have an excel spreadsheet with 2 worksheets
worksheet 1 contains common locations for waste collection areas for blocks of flats.
Worksheet 2 contains the actual properties that use those common locations.

There are 115 locations in worksheet 1 and 1300 in worksheet 2.

Each worksheet has a common ID column.

I'm trying to set worksheet 1 up so that when i click on the ID column, Worksheet 2 only shows the properties that use that location.

I've tried using the `HYPERLINK` function to open the second worksheet but it displays all the records.

Can anyone help with solving this problem?

edit: Thursday morning
thanks for the responses so far, hopefully you can see the images i'e linked to at the bottom

The common column in the spreadsheets is UPRN in Areas and Cross_reference in Properties

My eventual result would be to be able to click on the UPRN field (in Areas) which would then display all the records in Properties with that same cross_reference.

Using the first record in Areas (28059497) as an example, that would show 12 records in Properties

thanks

Simon Hume

[Areas spreadsheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wY7g.png)

[Properties spreadsheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcJ33.png)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you please edit your question to include screenshots of your problem so it would be easier to understand? Thank you!

Comment: Hard to tell without more information, but it sounds like a Pivot Table solution could work for you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to Worksheet2 filter automatically based on Worksheet 1? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Simon Hume, I can suggest two possible methods to Find related properties when you Click/Select the Common Id (UPRN). One is VBA(Macro) another is Excel Formula. Just confirm through comments which one you need !!

Comment: @Lee - yes, when the user selects the UPRN in Areas, it filters out the records in Properties

Comment: @Rajesh - Excel formula, i might understand what you're doing then!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Write this Array Formula in Cell `E21` of Sheet1, finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` then fill right & Down.**

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$E$10:$I$17, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($D$21, Sheet2!$D$10:$D$17), ROW(Sheet2!$E$10:$I$17)-MIN(ROW(Sheet2!$E$10:$I$17))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),""))}
```

**How it works:**

- Write the UPRN in Cell D21. You may create a Drop Down also for faster process.
- Change UPRN or select from Drop Down(if Created) for other match from Sheet2.
- As soon you write/change the UPRN Excel will extract multiple match from Sheet2 for UPRN in Cell D21 (for example 28059497).

**Note:**

- *This Formula will work properly if in Sheet 2 it finds similar UPRN.*
- Remember in attached Screen Shots with the Question by you I've not found duplicate UPRNs in Properties Sheet.

**Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.**